# How to control when TextBox Text as binding source updates the target value?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, lost-focus

Trying for a simple thing. I want `TextBlock` text to be updated to what `TextBox`'s text value is. However, I want it to happen only on `LostFocus`. Currently below code updates a `TextBlock` as user is typing into a `TextBox`. How do we achieve that?

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox x:Name="txtQty" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=txtQty, Path=Text}" />
</StackPanel>
```

I explored the `UpdateSourceTrigger` property on textbox with `LostFocus`, but it won't work as that controls how the source should be updated, whereas here I need how the destination updates.

I prefer to have a XAML only solution.

Comment: Why don't you just bind the TextBlock and the TextBox to the same view model property?

Answer (score 2):

XAML is a *markup* language.

The straight-forward way to to this would be to bind the `TextBox` and the `TextBlock` to the same view model source property. The source property will be set when the `TextBox` loses focus and then the `TextBlock` will then be updated provided that the view model class implements the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface as expected.

You could of course also handle the `LostKeyboardFocus` event for the `TextBox` and set the `Text` property of the `TextBlock` programmatically in the code-behind of the view. This approach is not any worse than trying to implement some logic in the XAML markup of the very same view. Just because you possibly *can* do something in pure XAML, it doesn't mean that you always should. A programming language such as C# usually does a better job implementing some logic.

Answer (score 1):

As others already said, the best way would be to bind the `TextBlock` and the `TextBox` to the same viewmodel property.

If you want to do it only with XAML code you could try it from the other side and bind your `TextBox` to the `TextBlock`.
Like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox  Text="{Binding ElementName=txtQty, Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtQty" />
</StackPanel>
```